# How to use Propensity Score Matching on a multinomial outcome (with 5 unordered categories) on STATA?

Tags: stata, propensity-scores, matching

I'm trying to use PSM on a dependent variable with 5 categories on STATA. I have tried teffects and psmatch2 but they didn't work. Error message shows there is no such outcome model specification (with mlogit). I wonder if anybody know how to do it?

Thank you very much!